# 1. How do you use the influence.SEM package? 2. Is it the only function you use to identify outliers?

Tags: r-lavaan, structural-equation-model

Since I have read that many experts advise against continuing to calculate with estimated factor values for the latent variables, I have stopped using the following function:

```
reg.fit.dv1 <- lm(data= df, A ~ estimated_factor_value_B + estimated_factor_value_C)

ols_plot_resid_lev(reg.fit.dv1)
```

And switched to the functions of the influence.SEM package.

```
Deltachi(mod,df) # 1st Graph
genCookDist(mod, df) # 3nd Graph
Likedist(mod, df) # 2nd Graph
```

All these three functions give me slightly different values (a lot in total, see graphs).

But which values should I now exclude? Values that are output by all three functions?

How do you do that? Or do you use estimated factor values like in my first equation?

[Pictures of Outlier Graphs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4q98R.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

You can find the descriptions of change in chi-square and generalized Cook's distance (gCD) in this paper:

Pek, J., & MacCallum, R. (2011). Sensitivity analysis in structural equation models: Cases and their influence. *Multivariate Behavioral Research, 46*(2), 202–228. https://doi.org/10.1080/00273171.2011.561068

The two values measures different aspects of the influence of a case. The change in chi-square measures influence on model fit because many fit measures depends on chi-square. The gCD measures overall influence on parameter estimates. Likelihood distance, also described in Pek and MacCallum (2011), is closely related to the change in chi-square.

I recommend examining why this case is high on one or more of these values, instead of excluding it right away. The following reference is a good and comprehensive one, in my opinion:

Aguinis, H., Gottfredson, R. K., & Joo, H. (2013). ​Best-​p​ractice ​recommendations for ​defining, ​identifying, and ​handling ​outliers. *Organizational Research Methods, 16*(2), 270–301. https://doi.org/10.1177/1094428112470848

Basically, the suitable approach is to see what happened first. For example, maybe a case is influential because a score was incorrectly computed (error outliers, Aguinins, Gottfredson, & Joo, 2013, Table 1). It may not longer be an influential case when this error is fixed.